# Making a website widget SEO compliant - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, hashbang

I've recently been briefed to add a widget to a client's site which will allow a user to interact with different parts of an image, and drill down to more detailed information about what they are clicking on. This is all fine, and is something I've done many more times before. And if this was part of a site I was in control of, I'd know how to make it SEO compliant.

However, it must be hosted on the client's company website, and there are some technical restrictions on how anything I build must work on there. Notably that we can add a single custom HTML page as part of the site for our widget, but this page must load everything. So whilst we can upload as many other HTML files as we like, only this single file will ever be part of the site structure, with the header, legft navigation, etc.

And this approach usually works fine. We place some JavaScript in the skeleton HTML page, and this does all the heavy lifting - loading any additional HTML pages via Ajax as required.

However, the client has insisted that each section of the widget be optimised for SEO, and be crawl-able by Google. Now if this was on a site I had control over, I would create each section of the widget as a separate HTML page - with it's own title, description, URL, etc - and then load them via Ajax.

But as the client is only allowing one page which is part of the site, this won't work in this case. I can obviously add other HTML pages with their own SEO meta tags - but if there were viewed in the browser, they'd just have the widget's content - no left navigation, header, etc.

So what is the solution here? The SEO obviously breaks as Google (or other search engine) will return the URL to these standalone pages, which just breaks the site experience entirely.

Am I right in thinking there isn't any way of doing it unless the client allows us to create every single like for like page on their website?

Comment: have you read the google developer guidelines for ajax loaded pages that explain `?_escaped_fragment=` ?

Comment: Yep, and I understand the mechanism - but it doesn't solve the problem of the additional pages being 'outside' of the main site. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: exactly, unless you can provide such a fallback I don't think you can meet the SEO requirements mentioned. Using `?_escaped_fragment` you don't need all the headers repeated so long as google can access the live links

Comment: Okay - looks like we'll have to go back to the client and request what we need. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

consider the Widget are a part of website page content only. There is no any separate tags for widget you can specify title,description, etc.,

Only you can do is that the content which you displaying should be well formatted and well display with properly...

Let say you use hyperlinks use title tag, if image then use alt tags, add bulleted points, add number points, add keyword hyperlink to another article, etc.,

this will help you to get links crawled and get link juice for your internal and the content can make seo friendly.

1. Use Title Tags.
2. Meta Description Tags.
3. Header Tags.
4. Add Alt Tags in Images.
5. Building Links.
6. Add Open Graph Tags.
7. Social Linking Pages Card
8. Tags.
9. The Robots Tag.
10. Mobile Friendly CSS optimization

SEO Optimization can be done for each HTML Page that you can follow some rules and tips to optimize the page content SEO friendly, you can analyze your website main page [here](https://websiteseostats.com/) this tool provide all SEO optimization tips that you can fix to rank in google search.